# PHP: order array with a user-defined comparison function and alphabetically by two values

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

it's my first post and I hope I do not make any mistakes.

I have a choir memberlist as array:

```
$members = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Bert
        [1] => T
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Claudia
        [1] => S
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => Alfred
        [1] => T 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => Kevin
        [1] => B
    [4] => Array ( 
        [0] => Antonia
        [1] => S
    [5] => Array (
        [0] => Jessica
        [1] => A)
);
```

Now I want to order the list as follow:

1. Order by voice: S(opran), A(lt), T(enor), B(ass)
2. Order by surname alphabetically

Ordering by voice is done with this code:

```
$order = array('S','A','T','B');

uasort($members, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a[1], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b[1], $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
```

How can I order the array by surname without loosing the voice order?

Thanks for your help and food for thought.

Joachim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you flip the `$order` array before using it in the comparison function, you can avoid the multiple `array_search` calls. After that, it's just a matter of applying the sort criteria in the correct order.

```
$order = array_flip($order);
uasort($members, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    return $order[$a[1]] - $order[$b[1]] ?: strcasecmp($a[0], $b[0]);
});
```

The voice order is retained this way because the name comparison will only be done if the voice comparison returns 0, so it only functions as a tie breaker.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with the help of `strcasecmp()` in your existing callback function :

```
uasort($members, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a[1], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b[1], $order);
    if($pos_a == $pos_b) { // Same voice : check the name instead to order both items
        return strcasecmp($a[0],$b[0]);
    }
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
```

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php